# Basic Python Function replacing values

Tags: python, string

I am attempting to create a function with the following characteristics;

function name: new_scores,

parameters: (p1_score,p2_score,current_score,current_player)

`p1_score`: user inputed player 1 score,

`p2_score`: user inputed player 2 score,

`current_score`: the current score of set player after any actions performed

`current_player`: either 'PLAYER_ONE' or 'PLAYER_TWO'

the problem with my code is that it doesnt work in all cases, for example try replacing values in PLAYER_ONE, it just spits back out the p1_score, and p2_score that i inputed. Thanks for the help

```
def new_scores(p1_score,p2_score,current_score,current_player):
    if current_player == 'PLAYER_ONE':
        p1_score = current_score
        return (p1_score,p2_score)
    elif current_player == 'PLAYER_TWO':
        p2_score = current_score
        return (p1_score,p2_score)
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the code you use to call this function :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is needlessly complex, which is quite the feat for so few lines. :) There's no point in the assignment, just return the intended data directly:

```
def new_scores(p1_score, p2_score, current_score, current_player):
   if current_player == 'PLAYER_ONE':
      return (current_score, p2_score)
   elif current_player == 'PLAYER_TWO':
      return (p1_score, current_score)
```

Still, your code looks correct. Verify that the parameters are correct, using strings for semantics like this is a bit error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are *using* the returned value and not expecting the parameters you passed in to be altered as a side effect.

```
>>> new_scores(3, 4, 5, "PLAYER_ONE")
(5, 4)
>>> new_scores(3, 4, 7, "PLAYER_TWO")
(3, 7)
```

Running your function as above shows it works as expected